# USB Headphones not working

Tags: release-freya

I recently just installed freya..and my logitech USB headphones seem to not work. I saw other people suggest unmuting them in alsamixer, I did that, but that did not fix anything. My speakers work just fine, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: are those USB headphones?

Comment: Yes they are, sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem to this, headphones didn't work automatically but they appeared in Switchboard under sound, there I could switch to them and they worked normally, try doing this first.

If it works then to make this happen automatically when you connect them open the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa` as root and add the following line to the end:

`load-module module-switch-on-connect`

Then reboot or run the command `pacmd load-module module-switch-on-connect`